# Date picture format error

Tags: sql, datetime, oracle10g

Could anyone suggest what is wrong with this format of date?

```
select to_date('04-Oct-2012 10:22:54,dd-Mon-YYYY hh24:mi:ss') from dual
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to add `''`  as below:

```
select to_date('04-Oct-2012 10:22:54','dd-Mon-YYYY hh24:mi:ss') 
from dual
```

### [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/8edae/1/0) Demo

Answer (score 3):

It should be:

```
select to_date('04-Oct-2012 10:22:54','dd-Mon-YYYY hh24:mi:ss') from dual
```

OUTPUT: `October, 04 2012 10:22:54+0000`

Demo:

### [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/3025/0)

Answer (score 2):

You appear to be missing a set of `''` around the `,`

Try this instead:

```
select to_date('04-Oct-2012 10:22:54','dd-Mon-YYYY hh24:mi:ss') from dual
```